# asp.net List(of CustomObject) design

Tags: asp.net

I've got a page that will bind a List(of CustomObject) to a gridview. The twist is that 'CustomObject' could be one of 3 different types of object (CustObjA, CustObjB, CustObjC). The page will not know what type of objects it is going to display until after the postback occurs (after there is a trip to the database to retrieve the objects). I build my grid dynamically from the codebehind depending on what the current Object type is. I'm finding that my code-behind is beginning to need a lot of "if typeOf object is..." statements, and I'd like to get away from that. Maybe a List isn't the way to do it - looking for any suggestions. I'm using vb.net/vstudio 2010/webforms.
thanks.

Comment: I did think of using an interface, but then while I am processing the page - users will interact with the gridview - if I have a List of (IMyInterface), will I be able to convert that to a list of (ICustObjA)? I'll need to do that. I didn't think you could cast a list except for looping through it and casting each item.

Comment: Interface perfectly fits your main task that you mentioned. Other details are hidded ) a number of constraints that you mentioned may indicate confusing design. Thus you'd better show us a bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use inheritence so CustObjA, B, C have the same superclass or inteface?

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement an interface, that gives you access to data and receive a list of objects of such type.